# 'component' is not a known element in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem when i work with angular, this is my project structure (begin from app folder, please look at super-admin folder) :

```
- Modules
---- home [+]
---- admin [+]
---- super-admin
-------- super-admin-routing.module.ts
-------- super-admin.module.ts
-------- (And html, scss, component file)
-------- pages
------------ auth [+]
------------ unauth [+]
------------ shared
---------------- shared.component.ts
---------------- (And html, scss file)
- cores [+]
- config [+]
- shared [+]
- strores [+]
- app-routing.module.ts
- app.module.ts
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './modules/home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './modules/admin/admin.component';
import { SuperAdminComponent } from './modules/super-admin/super-admin.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: "admin",
        component: AdminComponent
    },
    {
        path: "super-admin",
        component: SuperAdminComponent,
        loadChildren: './modules/super-admin/super-admin.module#SuperAdminModule'
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        component: HomeComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        AdminComponent,
        SuperAdminComponent
    ],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

super-admin.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SuperAdminRoutingModule } from './super-admin-routing.module';
import { SharedComponent } from './pages/shared/shared.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SuperAdminRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [SharedComponent]
})
export class SuperAdminModule { }
```

super-admin-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './pages/auth/auth.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: "",
        component: AuthComponent,
        loadChildren: "./pages/auth/auth.module#AuthModule"
    },
    {
        path: "home",
        component: AuthComponent,
        loadChildren: "./pages/auth/auth.module#AuthModule"
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        component: AuthComponent
    },
    
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent,
        AuthComponent
    ],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SuperAdminRoutingModule { }
```

super-admin.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-shared></app-shared>
```

and finaly is shared.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shared',
  templateUrl: './shared.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shared.component.scss']
})
export class SharedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Please look at `super-admin.module.ts` file, i imported and declared ShareComponent in `super-admin.module.ts` but i can't use it in `super-admin.component.html`, it's say:

> 'app-shared' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-shared' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-shared' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I think i miss something right?

I `ng s` it for 7 times but it still not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your super-admin.component belongs to the app.module.ts you need to export the **`SharedComponent`** from the SuperAdminModule and import **`SuperAdminModule`**  in your app.module.ts

Change super-admin.module as,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SuperAdminRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [SharedComponent],
  exports : [SharedComponent]
})
```

**`EDIT`** As mentioned in the comment, add it in the app.routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        AdminComponent,
        SuperAdminComponent
    ],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), SuperAdminModule],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, it's still not work when i export `ShareComponent` from `super-admin` and import `super-admin.module` into `app.module`. But it will work when i add it into `app-routing.module`. Yup, you save my time, thank you!

Comment: Adding to app-routing.module.ts did the trick. But how come it's working when added app-routing.module.ts instead of app.module.ts?

Answer (score 2):

If you are declaring any of the Component in Module and want to import in other module, make sure you are exporting your Component.

### super-admin.module as,

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SuperAdminRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [SharedComponent],
      exports : [SharedComponent]
    })
export class SuperAdminModule { }
```

Importing the component into other module. You must ensure that Shared Module is imported into module where you are using the exported component.

### app-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        AdminComponent,
        SuperAdminComponent
    ],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), SuperAdminModule],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, this is the reason code not work, i'm forget export from `super-admin.module` and import into `app.routing`. Thank you